# Detecting intersections in Gmsh

Tags: mesh

I'm considering to use gmsh as replacement of Ansys mesher (obviating there is not mesh file type compatibility for Workbench/APDL).

I want to implement an algorithm to introduce spheres (later it will be any type of volume) in a cube. They should not touch each other, therefore I need to check if the volume I'm introducing intersect with any of the volumes I introduced before.

Ideally, it will be nice to have a command which checks the boundaries. I saw there are some commands like `Boundary`, `PointsOf` and `CombinedBoundary` which seems to retrieve the entities on the boundaries. But I'm not sure how they work (the documentation does not explain what happens when there are no boundaries).
I tried to use those commands in the GUI, but I couldn't find them.

Other option, but slower, is to try the intersection command (not deleting any of the original volumes) and check how many volumes are after the intersection. If there are more than before, there is an intersection. But I'm not very happy with this solution. Anyway, I will need to be able to count the number of volumes before and after, which I haven't seen anything like in the gmsh documentation.

So, my question is: Is it possible to detect interstions in gmsh before actually perform the intersections? Is it possible to count the number of volumes (I guess yes)?

Thank very much. Kind regards,

Comment: a quick comment: most of GMSH commands are not available via GUI, so you might have to go into the text editor to edit the GEO file yourself.

Comment: Hi @Anton thank very much for your suggestion. I'm trying to do that now. Using the text editor, but I'm not sure how to detect the intersection.

Comment: I haven't done it either, otherwise, I would have already provided an answer. I might get back to you on the weekend if I figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can count intersections before doing the intersection, but you can remove the objects that are created by the intersection after getting information by using the [GMSH API](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/tree/master/demos/api)  ([download here](http://gmsh.info/) "SDK"). I've been using python, the documentation in the source files is fairly clear, as well as the numerous demos.

Because its in python, you can count entities easily using commands like:

```
len(model.getEntities(3))  # returns number of volume entities
```

My solution involves computing the intersection (with removeObject=False, removeTool=False), then finding the length of the returned list. If there are volumes created by intersection, you have an intersection. From there you can either give yourself a warning, or remove the intersections etc.

An example python script:

```
import gmsh  # Download gmsh.py, and libgmsh files from gmsh-sdk

model = gmsh.model
factory = model.occ
mesh = model.mesh

gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.CharacteristicLengthMax", 0.2)  # max mesh size
# gmsh.option.setNumber("General.Terminal", 1)  # can be useful
model.add("Example")  # add a model

 # Create overlapping boxes (can be any shapes)
b1 = (3, factory.addBox(0,0,0, 1, 1, 1))  # 1x1x1 box with "bottom left" at 0,0,0
b2 = (3, factory.addBox(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1))

 # Calculate the intersection. With removeObject, removeTool as False, this 
 # creates an object if there is an intesection
intersect = factory.intersect([b1], [b2], removeObject=False, removeTool=False)[0]
factory.synchronize()

if len(intersect):
    # if there is an intersection, do what you want to do.
    factory.remove(intersect, True)  # remove created intersection objects
    factory.synchronize()

mesh.generate(3)

 # Visualise
model.setVisibility(model.getEntities(3),0)  # turn volumes off
gmsh.fltk.run()  # start gmsh
gmsh.finalize()
```

I hope this helps - I'm sure this could be done with normal .GEO files, but I prefer/think its easier to work in Python.

Comment: Hi Duncan. I actually move on, but if I find the time, I will try to follow your code. Thank very much!